# changing media library based image file path (date generated) WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Is there any possible way, I can update an image *(generated file path)* via Wordpress CMS media library upload?

For instance, say, on December 2014 I upload an arrow image to [Wordpress Media Library](http://codex.wordpress.org/Media_Library_Screen) upload area, then it gives me the below file location path. **I would like to alter.**

```
acoolwebsite.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/right_arrow.png
```

Specifically I would like to change the **date area**.. to a custom one for maintenance purposes. `/2014/12/`

Any suggestions here? `Functions.php` alteration to allow, or some reputable plugins? `(I'll even take some JS hacky options if any ideas)`

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for all uploads? only some uploads? Do you want to be able to edit the path yourself, or is this something that will be done programatically only?

Comment: I actually would just like to alter 2 image file paths @Ohgodwhy - but it would be kind of cool to have the option globally.